# C++ class template constructor -- overload reference(U&) with array(U*) failed

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor, constructor-overloading

I am trying to build a constructor to take an array as an argument which overloads another who take a scalar instead. Code is below.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class SmallVec { // This is a 3 dimensional vector class template
public:
    T data[3] = {0}; // internal data of class
    template <typename U>
    explicit SmallVec(const U& scalar) { // if a scalar, copy it to each element in data
        for(auto &item : data) {
            item = static_cast<T>(scalar);
        }
    }
    template <typename U>
    explicit SmallVec(const U* vec) { // if a vector, copy one by one
        for(auto &item : data) {
            item = static_cast<T>(*vec); 
            vec++;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    float num = 1.2;
    float *arr = new float[3];
    arr[2] = 3.4;
    SmallVec<float> vec1(num); // take num, which works fine
    SmallVec<float> vec2(arr); // !!!--- error happens this line ---!!!
    std::cout << vec1.data[2] << " "  << vec2.data[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains that

```
error: invalid static_cast from type 'float* const' to type 'float'
```

Obviously, `vec2(arr)` still calls the first constructor. However, if I remove `template <typename U>` and replace `U` to `T`. The program just works fine. What should I do to correct this?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Hint: The first constructor is called both times.

Comment: @LogicStuff Thank you so much for the prompt comment. Yes, the first constructor is called again. This probably means array (or pointer to array) is passed by reference? But how should I tell the program to find the second constructor, or how should I distinguish if argument is scalar or array in the first method? Would you give me some more hints please?

Comment: You'll have to use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) or tag dispatching.

Comment: @LogicStuff Or use `explicit SmallVec(U* vec)` instead of `explicit SmallVec(const U* vec)`. Or use `SmallVec<float> vec2(static_cast<const float *>(arr));` instead of `SmallVec<float> vec2(arr);`.

Comment: @LogicStuff That's helpful! Thank you a lot for informing me these topics to look up! :-)

Comment: @skypjack I'm grateful that you raised a great point on the `const`. I didn't notice such a subtle difference. If I understand it correctly -- since I use `const U* vec`, when `arr` is passed, the argument deduction happens? Maybe that's why the program turns to the first construct and finds it acceptable instead choosing the second one immediately, right? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to build a constructor to take an array as an argument

(...)

> ```
> explicit SmallVec(const U* vec) { // if a vector, copy one by one
> ```

You do not take an array. You take **a pointer, which may or may not point to an array**, and even if it points to an array, who says that the array has at least three elements? That's a serious design flaw.

C++ does allow you to take raw arrays by reference or const reference, even though the syntax is horrible:

```
explicit SmallVec(const U (&vec)[3]) {
```

The implementation of the constructor is then also different:

```
    for(int index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
        data[index] = static_cast<T>(vec[index]); 
    }
```

Looking at `main`, however, the problem goes deeper. You use `new[]` to allocate an array dynamically. That's already a very bad idea. Coincidentally, your example also misses a `delete[]`. Why don't you use a local array instead?

```
 float arr[3];
```

This will make your program compile and probably run correctly, but there's still undefined behaviour in your code, because you only set the 3rd element of the array to a valid value; the other two elements remain uninitialised, and reading from an uninitialised `float`, even if you just copy it, formally results in undefined behaviour.

So better make it:

```
 float arr[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 3.4 };
```

In addition to that, C++11 invites you to use `std::array`, which generally makes things a bit safer and improves the syntax. Here is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
class SmallVec { // This is a 3 dimensional vector class template
public:
    std::array<T, 3> data; // internal data of class
    template <typename U>
    explicit SmallVec(const U& scalar) { // if a scalar, copy it to each element in data
        for(auto &item : data) {
            item = static_cast<T>(scalar);
        }
    }
    template <typename U>
    explicit SmallVec(std::array<U, 3> const& vec) { // if a vector, copy one by one
        for(int index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
            data[index] = static_cast<T>(vec[index]); 
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    float num = 1.2;
    std::array<float, 3> arr = { 0.0, 0.0, 3.4 };
    SmallVec<float> vec1(num);
    SmallVec<float> vec2(arr);
    std::cout << vec1.data[2] << " "  << vec2.data[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation! That's helpful. Yes, it was my fault. I originally used `arr[3]`, then I thought I should give a pointer to the constructor, so I changed to `new[]` but forgot `delete []`. Now I understand I was wrong about passing a pointer to an array. Yes, variables defined inside functions will be uninitialized and I should avoid these undefined behaviors. I appreciate that you point it out. :-)   I will be careful when I ask questions later.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to use SFINAE to get what you want:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
  struct Foo {

    template <class U, typename enable_if<is_pointer<U>::value, int>::type = 0>
      Foo(U u){}

    template <class U, typename enable_if<!is_pointer<U>::value, int>::type = 0>
      Foo(U u){}

  };


int main()
{
  Foo<int> f('a'); // calls second constructor
  Foo<int> f2("a"); // calls first constructor
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/ZPcb5T

Comment: The compiler do detect `float*` for the first one, but it detects `float` for the second one which then takes `const float *` and the overload resolution choose the first one because of this `const` not because of the `**`.

Comment: @xaxxon Thank you so much for providing a solution with SFIANE and `std::enable_if`. It is readable and clear. I am still learning C++, and the reason why I reply so late is because I could not find the correct resources to understand the `= 0` part in template arguments. I see that `enable_if<is_pointer<U>::value, int>::type` is `int` if `U` is a pointer in the first constructor. But what does `= 0` accomplish in it? Would you please give me some explanations or some hints/link? I really appreciate it! :-)

Comment: it creates a second template parameter.  Specifically it is a non-type (template parameters can also be integral values), un-named (as in you can't use it because it isn't named) parameter with a default value of 0 (because it has a default value, the caller doesn't have to specify it).   Basically it's a "trick" that let's you throw in some arbitrary code for the sole purpose of having a SFINAE check without affecting your "real" function types.    Often you'd do this with the return type, but since it's a constructor, you can't do that because you don't specify the return type.

Comment: For the one that passes the SFINAE check, it ends up just being `template<class U, int = 0> Foo(...){}`

Comment: If you're bleeding edge, you can clean it up a bit: https://godbolt.org/g/lgX0MI  but is_pointer_v is only in c++17  - though you can make it yourself if you want.   enable_if_t is c++14

Comment: @xaxxon I'm eternally grateful that you described it so precisely. I googled and read quite a lot and learned a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Even though both constructors use the explicit specifier and try to avoid type conversions you should note that the first is just as good a candidate as the second. If you substitute U for float* you will get:

explicit SmallVec(const float*& scalar)

which is totally acceptable and will explain the compilation error.
You could resolve the problem by changing the second constructor to:

```
template <typename U>
explicit SmallVec(U* const vec) { // if a vector, copy one by one
    U* local = vec;
    for(auto &item : data) {
        item = static_cast<T>(*local);
        local++;
    }
}
```

However, I suggest an even more explicit way:

```
class ScalarCopy {};
class VectorCopy {};

...

template <typename U>
SmallVec(const U& vec, ScalarCopy);

template <typename U>
SmallVec(const U* const vec, VectorCopy);
```

and make explicit calls:

```
SmallVec<float> vec1(num, ScalarCopy());
SmallVec<float> vec2(arr, VectorCopy());
```

Comment: You are changing the signature with the first one which is not really good since you are allowing the constructor to modify the value of `vec`.

Comment: True. That is another reason to prefer the second more explicit solution.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the suggestions. You make it clear where my fault is. :-)

Comment: Instead of using tag classes, you can also make the constructor private and add two public static functions like `SmallVec::fromScalar` and `SmallVec::fromVector`. Both would return `SmallVec<T>` and call the private constructor internally to create the new object.